# XSLT with value of select in URL string

Tags: xslt

I want to combine some XSL with XML and put out the resulting HTML.

My XSl contains this line which doesnt work:

```
<a href="www.domain.com/account/business/get/?t=2&amp;id=<xsl:value-of select="row/objectid"/>">Click here</a>
```

The desired output would be:

```
<a href="www.domain.com/account/business/get/?t=2&id=6">Click here</a>
```

The code works when I leave out the `<xsl:value-of select="row/objectid"/>` part in the URL. It also works when I place the `<xsl:value-of select="row/objectid"/>` outside the hyperlink tag, so i KNOW the value-of-select to be correct by itself.

So I suspect that the quotes are messing things up...how can I fix this?

PS. I tried replacing `"` with `'` as well

Comment: pls show the surround XSL code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stylesheet should contain well-formed XML, so you can't include the output from `value-of` in an attribute. Use an attribute value template instead:

```
<a href="www.domain.com/account/business/get/?t=2&amp;id={row/objectid}"
  >Click here</a>
```

The expression in curly braces will be evaluated and replaced with its output.

Comment: I think double-quote before `{row` is misplaced.